# How can I check if a page is available offline in HTML5?

Tags: html, local-storage, offline, offline-mode, offline-caching

I want to create a magazine reader in HTML5. One feature I'd like to add is ability to read articles while being offline.

I'd like to show a list of previously accessed articles and still available offline. The problem is that I don't know if it's possible to check if a given URL is available in a user's offline cache or not. I could store previously accessed URLs in local storage but I can't be sure if these URLs are still available in the cache. Is it possible to be notified when a given URL is removed from the cache or check if the URL is available offline?

Thanks,
Michal

Answer (score 0):

There's no way in the HTML5 spec. Firefox has an experimental [mozItems](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIDOMOfflineResourceList) property of window.applicationCache, but it seems to not work: always has a length of 0. I don't know if webkit has anything similar.

Comment: Isn't it very restrictive? How could one implement an email client without knowing which mails are available offline? Users would have to click and check which one is available...
Are there any alternatives?

Comment: There are LOTS of problems with this feature / spec. If a single item in your manifest fails to load, the entire cache gets invalidated. If you update any of the files, you need to update the manifest file too or the users will continue using their offline version. If you're offline, browsers will throw DOM_CONNECTION_ERROR regardless of whether your application is still able to function. And it is extremely difficult to debug what's going wrong when it isn't working. BUT hey, it's better than nothing.

Comment: @Gaurav that's because it only contains *dynamically*-managed entries added using `mozAdd`.